# Yii Create Command Sort

Tags: yii

I am looking to sort by ASC or DESC and am not quite sure how to do this using Yii, my code below is as follows but I am not sure where to order by as I need to order by DESC for timestamp and ASC for homeTeamName.

```
    $query= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                  ->select('*')
                  ->from('livematch')
                  ->where('DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 7 DAY')
                  ->order(array('timestamp', 'homeTeamName'))
                  ->queryAll();
```

Any help on this would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it directly like below:

```
$query= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
              ->select('*')
              ->from('livematch')
              ->where('DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 7 DAY')
              ->order(array('timestamp', 'homeTeamName desc'))
              ->queryAll();
```

which means: `ORDER BY timestamp,homeTeamName DESC`

Answer (score 2):

try like this ,

```
$query  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM livematch where DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 7 DAY order by timestamp desc" );
$std_list = $query->queryAll();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I needed it to be formatted like the above, I know this does the same thing so thank you.